# NSDate dateFromString returns null

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am saving a date that has been converted to a string to a plist when the app exits. When the viewDidLoad is run I am trying to read the string back in and convert it back to a date. The string saves to the plist and reads in correctly but will not convert back to a date. I am using the standard format given by the NSDate date command. Time1 is always null.

The output looks like this:

```
time1string = 2010-07-07 13:47:12 -0500
time1 = (null)
```

The code looks like this:

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)notification {
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[array addObject: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", time1]];

[array writeToFile:[self dataFilePath] atomically:YES];
[array release];

NSLog(@"APP Terminating, Persisting Data");
```

}

-(void)viewDidLoad {

```
NSLog(@"View did load");
NSString *filePath = [self dataFilePath];
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

    NSString *time1string = [array objectAtIndex:1];
    NSLog(@"time1string = %@",time1string);
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss Z"];
    time1 = [dateFormat dateFromString:time1string];
    NSLog(@"time1 = %@",time1);
    [dateFormat release];
    [array release];

}
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(applicationWillTerminate:)
                                             name:UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification 
                                           object:app];
 [super viewDidLoad];
```

}

Comment: Can you show your declaration for time1?

Comment: From the FAQ

>When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer. This lets other people know that you have received a good answer to your question. Doing this is helpful because it shows other people that you're getting value from the community. (If you don't do this, people will often politely ask you to go back and accept answers for more of your questions!)>

Answer (score 8):

It looks like it's failing to parse because you're using the wrong date format.  Try using `@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"` instead.  The `hh` format requires an hour in the range 1-12, whereas `HH` uses 0-23.

See the [`Locale Data Markup Language`](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns) for the full reference on all of the patterns that can be used here (via [Data Formatters reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1)).

Comment: This answer seems legit. I've tried other answers that pointed out about the locale setting and all but none of them worked. And this works like a charm. The links also really helped.